# Js loop through nested object and return object value

Tags: javascript

i have a nested object with children that are arrays. I am trying to loop through an `encounter` array inside an object. The encounter also has an array called `obs`. My goal is to return a specific value with a uuid `161643AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` inside the obs children . So far i have this, i would like to reduce the time it takes to retrieve the value. Any assistance/links to read will be appreciated.

```
const x = visits && visits?.encounters.filter((visit) => {
    var y = visit?.obs.find((e) => {
      return e.concept.uuid === 161643AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    })
    return y
  })?.shift().obs.find((e) => e.concept.uuid === 161643AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)?.value.display;
```

My object looks like this :

```
{
      "uuid": "8d2579c0-e52b-4c9e-a4bd-03e83b9d4832",
      "encounters": [
        {
          "uuid": "a655f6d8-317b-4dc4-b395-8a29e34456bc",
          "form": {
            "uuid": "22c68f86-bbf0-49ba-b2d1-23fa7ccf0259",
            "display": "HIV Green Card"
          },
          "encounterDatetime": "2023-02-07T15:13:15.000+0300",
          "obs": [
            {
              "uuid": "1fc8f4d0-6038-4d58-b222-1b9b50f34da1",
              "concept": {
                "uuid": "161652AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                "display": "Cotrimoxazole adherence",
                "conceptClass": {
                  "uuid": "8d491e50-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f",
                  "display": "Question"
                }
              },
              "display": "Cotrimoxazole adherence: Not applicable",
              "groupMembers": null,
              "value": {
                "uuid": "1175AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                "display": "Not applicable",
                "name": {
                  "display": "Not applicable",
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "uuid": "9e7fd1f8-dd74-4860-bf9e-b2c30ab83114",
              "concept": {
                "uuid": "161643AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                "display": "Person attending facility",
                "conceptClass": {
                  "uuid": "8d491e50-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f",
                  "display": "Question"
                }
              },
              "display": "Person attending facility: SELF",
              "groupMembers": null,
              "value": {
                "uuid": "978AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                "display": "SELF",
                "name": {
                  "display": "SELF",
                },
              }
            },
          ],
          "encounterType": {
            "uuid": "a0034eee-1940-4e35-847f-97537a35d05e",
            "display": "HIV Consultation"
          },
        },
      ],
      "startDatetime": "2023-02-07T15:13:15.000+0300",
      "stopDatetime": "2023-02-13T09:19:41.000+0300",
    }
```

Comment: For the given object, looping should not take too much time. Are you sure you are facing any real problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops instead. A `.filter()` followed by a `.shift()` can typically be replaced with `.find()`. However, both `.filter()` and `.find()` only return elements from the array you're calling the method on. Since you want to obtain a value nested within `obs` which is nested within `encounters`, you can instead use a regular [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, and return early from the loop once you find a match. This is more efficient than your current solution as it doesn't do an additional iteration over `obs` and exits early as soon as it finds a match:

```js
const visits = { "uuid": "8d2579c0-e52b-4c9e-a4bd-03e83b9d4832", "encounters": [{ "uuid": "a655f6d8-317b-4dc4-b395-8a29e34456bc", "form": { "uuid": "22c68f86-bbf0-49ba-b2d1-23fa7ccf0259", "display": "HIV Green Card" }, "encounterDatetime": "2023-02-07T15:13:15.000+0300", "obs": [{ "uuid": "1fc8f4d0-6038-4d58-b222-1b9b50f34da1", "concept": { "uuid": "161652AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "display": "Cotrimoxazole adherence", "conceptClass": { "uuid": "8d491e50-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f", "display": "Question" } }, "display": "Cotrimoxazole adherence: Not applicable", "groupMembers": null, "value": { "uuid": "1175AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "display": "Not applicable", "name": { "display": "Not applicable", } } }, { "uuid": "9e7fd1f8-dd74-4860-bf9e-b2c30ab83114", "concept": { "uuid": "161643AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "display": "Person attending facility", "conceptClass": { "uuid": "8d491e50-c2cc-11de-8d13-0010c6dffd0f", "display": "Question" } }, "display": "Person attending facility: SELF", "groupMembers": null, "value": { "uuid": "978AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "display": "SELF", "name": { "display": "SELF", }, } }, ], "encounterType": { "uuid": "a0034eee-1940-4e35-847f-97537a35d05e", "display": "HIV Consultation" }, }, ], "startDatetime": "2023-02-07T15:13:15.000+0300", "stopDatetime": "2023-02-13T09:19:41.000+0300", };

function findByConceptUUID(arr, id) {
  for(const visit of arr) {
    for(const obs of visit.obs) {
      if(obs.concept.uuid === id) {
        return obs.value.display;
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(findByConceptUUID(visits.encounters, "161643AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")); // SELF
```